# How can I deserialize a JSON array of "name" "value" pairs to a Pojo using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I want to deserialize the following JSON object:

```
{
  "id":"001",
  "module_name":"Users",
  "name_value_list":
    {
      "user_name": {"name":"user_name", "value":"admin"},
      "full_name": {"name":"full_name", "value":"Lluís Pi"},
      "city": {"name":"full_name", "value":"Barcelona"},
      "postal_code": {"name":"postal_code", "value":"08017"},
      ...
    }
}
```

into some Java object like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
public class UserEntry
{
  private String id;
  private String moduleName;
  private Person nameValueList;

  public String getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public String getModuleName()
  {
    return moduleName;
  }

  public Person getPerson()
  {
    return nameValueList;
  }
}
```

where Person is the following class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
class Person 
{
  private String userName;
  private String fullName;
  private String city;
  private String postalCode;
}
```

using Jackson but I get a deserialization error.

If I change the type of field `nameValueList` to a Map all the deserialization process goes with no problem and I get a map where the key is the "name" value and the value is the "value" value.

So my question is: is there any simple, or no so simple, way to deserialize this kind of JSON object to a Java Pojo with properties `prop_1`, `prop_2`, `prop_3`and `prop_4`?

```
{
  "name_value_list":
    {
      "prop_1": {"name":"prop_1", "value":"value_1"},
      "prop_2": {"name":"prop_2", "value":"value_2"},
      "prop_3": {"name":"prop_3", "value":"value_3"},
      "prop_4": {"name":"prop_4", "value":"value_4"},
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very simple and not very clean. However you can do it by implementing a *any* setter field for the JSON attributes in the Person class which don't match any attribute on your UserEntry POJO.

```
@JsonAnySetter
public void putUserField(String userKey, Map<String, String> userValue) 
  throws NoSuchFieldException {
    String actualFieldName = getActualFieldName(userKey);
    Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(actualFieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    ReflectionUtils.setField(field, this, userValue.get("value"));
}

private String getActualFieldName(String userKey) {
    return CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, userKey);
}
```

In addition to that, I had to change the Jackson attributes for the Person class to

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY, 
  getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
```

for it to work for attributes like "city" which don't need any name transformation because jackson tries to directly set the field which fails.

Comment: Yes, I figured out that using introspection was a solution, my problem was that this code has to work on Android where `java.beans.Introspector` is not available. Where your `ReflectionUtils` class comes from, do you know if it works on Android. I have been trying to find a similar approach using Jackson API but documentation is not very clear.

Comment: ReflectionUtils is a Spring class and CaseFormat is a Guava class. I am not sure if ReflectionUtils works on Android. You may as well test the above code on Android if you have the setup.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I found this https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Compatibility#Android

Comment: And yes, Spring ReflectionUtils only uses Android available Java classes.

Comment: FYI: this is another classic helper for Reflection related operations: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/